# Covariance of sample Spearman correlation coefficients

Tags: covariance, spearman-rho

Consider the bivariate probability distribution of $(X,Y)$. The Spearman correlation coefficient of $X$ and $Y$ is given by $$\rho_{X,Y} = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(R(X), R(Y))}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(R(X))\operatorname{Var}(R(Y))}},$$ where $R$ is the ranking function. Let $f$ and $g$ be two measurable functions, and define $U:=f(X)$ and $V:=g(Y)$. In general, $U$ and $X$ as well as $V$ and $Y$ are not independent anymore. Now suppose we estimated $\rho_{X,Y}$ and $\rho_{U,V}$ based on an observed an iid sample of $X$, $Y$, $U$, and $V$.

The estimators $\hat\rho_{X,Y}$ and $\hat\rho_{U,V}$ are random variables, and I want to compute the covariance $\operatorname{Cov}(\hat\rho_{X,Y},\hat\rho_{U,V})$. Clearly, if $f$ and $g$ are both monotone, $\hat\rho_{X,Y} = \hat\rho_{U,V}$ and the covariance equals the variance of $\hat\rho_{X,Y}$. I don't need to describe the covariance in terms of $f$ and $g$; I would be already very happy with a formula for the covariance of two dependend Spearman correlation coefficients.

Comment: Are you assuming that that $X$,$Y$ are continuous random variables? If so, then we know the distributions of $R(X)$ and $R(Y)$ are almost-surely uniform.

Comment: I would be fine with assuming continuity. However, I don't see how this helps me